# Multi-project, multi-user automated deployment

Tags: git, automation, bitbucket

I realise that automated deployment is a subject that has been well covered, however I can't find any questions that relate closely to my scenario.

We're looking to bring all of our version control under one roof, and streamline the process as much as possible.

Our setup is approximately 30 developers, working on anywhere between 90-130 individual projects at any one time.

At the moment we're looking at using BitBucket, however will eventually move across to a standalone solution running something like GitLab.

What I'm currently looking at achieving is automating the process between the repos and the staging server. Our current issue with this though is that I need something that isn't reliant on the command line. Ideally, it'll be a service that runs off a configuration file in the repo - like it seems [Dandelion](https://github.com/scttnlsn/dandelion) does. Also, ideally (I'm using that word a lot) we'll be able to specify which branch is deployed on update, and where to - allowing us to have branches that deploy to staging and also live environments if required.

Has anyone configured anything similar at all?

Comment: If someone would like to comment as to why they feel this should be closed, or point me in the direction of an answer that has already been posted, then I'd find that far more constructive than a simple down vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we've decided to do is develop our own solution based on the Hooks provided by Bitbucket. This way we can set it up and manage it in a way that exactly suits our workflow, even though the trade off is that the cost will be higher in the long run.